# ASP.net page gets error on import statement, but I do have the reference in place?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, import, reference

Any ideas why I am getting the below error in my MVC2 project, even through in the project itself I definitely have a reference to "system.Web.Entity"?

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Node>>" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Import Namespace="TopologyDAL" %>
Line 3:  <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Entity" %>
```

thanks

EDIT - By the way if I take out Line 3 then I get the error:

```
 Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Source Error:

Line 164:    
Line 165:    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()]
Line 166:    public class views_node_index_aspx : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Node>>, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler {
Line 167:        
Line 168:        private static bool @__initialized;


Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ec16fd2\a2147d7c\App_Web_index.aspx.1b64bdf1.ajruf7pv.0.cs    Line: 166
```

Comment: Do you have this assembly System.Data.Entity referenced in Web.config ? (<compilation> section)

Comment: no - I just added it to the references section of the project - is this an issue for asp.net is it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As [miensol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155213/miensol) suggested, try putting this in your `Web.config` file:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: Greg is the person who asked the question, the credit should go to miensol.

Comment: I have a console application. Where to create Web.config file? (There is one app.config file exists)

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to fiddling with the [`compilation.assemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfyb45k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) configuration is simply to mark the System.Data.Entity assembly as **"Copy Local"** in your solution.

This works due to the *root-level* `web.config` containing a [wildcard `add element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37e2zyhb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which causes all assemblies in your "private assembly cache" to be used during page compilation. From MSDN:

> The value of the add element is an assembly name, not a DLL path.
>   ASP.NET looks up the assembly name to find its physical DLL location.
>   Optionally, you can specify the asterisk (*) wildcard character to add
>   every assembly within the private assembly cache for the application,
>   which is located either in the \bin subdirectory of an application or
>   in the.NET Framework installation directory
>   (%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version).

Comment: Adding the assembly section to my web.config files (solution level and view level) alone did not work - I had to change the reference property "Copy Local" to "true" - Thanks Schneider

Answer (score 0):

Monish, the App.config file serves about the same purpose as the Web.config file, and adding an assembly is done the same way as it is done for a Web.config file.

```
<configuration>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies> 
            <add assembly="myassembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=9999999999999"/> 
        </assemblies> 
    </compilation>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides do you reference in web.config (as indicated above), you must:
Verify that the DLL files are in your project, for example within the BIN folder. If you want to know if the DLL is the correct version must go to C: \ Windows \ Assembly and verify that you have here the DLL versions with their respective PublicKeyToken you against your project. Copy the correct DLL, but do it using CMD (in Windows Explorer does not show the files) example typing CD C: \ Windows \ Assembly \ GAC_MSIL and copy the DLL you need.