# MVC, Views and System.Data.Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Repository Project that is added to my MVC application.

Within my C# code, of the MVC Web App, I have had to add a reference to System.Data.Entity so that I can access the objects from my Repository.

So the following fails if I do not have the reference added;

```
DataRepository<Store> repo = new DataRepository<Store>();
List<Store> allSorted = repo.All(x => x.name);
```

Now I want to pass that list to my Partial View, which sits within a FVM and it's the FVM that I pass to the Partial View.

So the index.aspx code;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<StoresFVM>" %>

<% Html.RenderPartial("StoreList", Model.StoreListFVM); %>
```

And the ASCX code;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<StoreListFVM>" %>

<%        
    SelectList storeList = new SelectList(Model.Stores.Select(x => new { Value = x.number, Text = x.name }),"Value","Text");
%>

<%= Html.DropDownList("SelectedStore", storeList) %>
```

However, I get an error informing me that I need to include a reference to System.Data.Entity in the ascx.  I don't get why for one.

I have tried adding the namespace to the web.config file and I have tried importing the namespace at the top of the ascx page.

Thoughts?

**EDIT**

> \nasfile02\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\TOM\TOM\Views\Stores\PartialViews\StoreList.ascx(4):
>   error CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

**EDIT**

```
namespace TOM.FormViewModels
{
    public class StoresFVM
    {
        public StoreListFVM StoreListFVM { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace TOM.FormViewModels
{
    public class StoreListFVM
    {
        public List<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Also you might want to look into [Razor Tags](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx). Using `<%` and `%>` is kind of outdated.

Comment: Error posted and as for Razor, well sure, but it's out of my hands

Comment: What exactly did you add to the web.config and what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally referenced the 2.0 version of System.Data.Entity?

Comment: Referencing v4.0.30319

Comment: Do both models have a "using" of System.Data.Entity?

Comment: No they don't.  Should they?

Comment: prob not :) but you could try.  
you tried adding it to the web.config: which one? you should add it to the web.config in the views folder and not the root web.config

Comment: tried both config files now w/out luck

Comment: And your web.config looks like http://stackoverflow.com/a/3611040/1737862?

Comment: JodyT, that was it!  write it up as the answer and i'll accept and vote.  Thanks

Comment: Didn't want to steal someone else's answer but it wouldn't let me post it without adding some more content. At least I referenced to Original answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should make sure the web.config looks as following:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Also described at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611040/1737862